# How to include complex entity fields in a projected entity framework object?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, repository, repository-pattern

I often use the `System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions` `Include()` method to cause complex entity fields to be included in query results from my repositories.  However, when I project my entities into new classes, I seem to lose this "concretization" of included complex entity fields.  For example, say I wanted to return an `Event` object from my repo, and be able to access the complex entity field `Assessment`:

```
public class EventRepository {
...
    public IList<Event> GetEvents() {
        using (var context = new MyDatabaseContext()) {
            return context.Events
                .Include(evnt => evnt.ActualAssessment)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
...
}
```

I can then run the following code without a hitch because of the `Include` I used above:

```
var repoEvents = new EventRepository();
var events = repoEvents.GetEvents();
Console.WriteLine(events[0].ActualAssessment.AssessmentDate.ToString());
```

But say I now want to project the `Event`s into a wrapper object `ExtendedEvent` with some extra info, like this:

```
public class EventRepository {
...
    public IList<ExtendedEvent> GetExtendedEvents() {
        using (var context = new MyDatabaseContext()) {
            return context.Events
                .Include(evnt => evnt.ActualAssessment)
                .Select(evnt => new {
                    TheEvent = evnt,
                    SomeExtraData = 123
                })
                .ToList()
                .Select(evntInfo => {
                    return new ExtendedEvent {
                        TheEvent = evntInfo.TheEvent,
                        SomeExtraData = evntInfo.SomeExtraData
                    };
                })
                .ToList();
        }
    }
...
}
```

I now try and run this code:

```
var repoEvents = new EventRepository();
var extendedEvents = repoEvents.GetExtendedEvents();
Console.WriteLine(extendedEvents[0].TheEvent.ActualAssessment.AssessmentDate.ToString());
```

This gives me the error "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection." - so `ActualAssessment` has not been eager-loaded despite my use of `Include`, apparently because I projected it into a new wrapper object.  How can I cause `ActualAssessment` to be included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `Include` is ignored in projections. What you can try is to make the related navigation property part of your projection into the anonymous object:

```
public IList<ExtendedEvent> GetExtendedEvents() {
    using (var context = new MyDatabaseContext()) {
        return context.Events
            .Select(evnt => new {
                TheEvent = evnt,
                SomeExtraData = 123,
                ActualAssessment = evnt.ActualAssessment
            })
            .ToList()
            .Select(evntInfo => {
                return new ExtendedEvent {
                    TheEvent = evntInfo.TheEvent,
                    SomeExtraData = evntInfo.SomeExtraData
                };
            })
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

The `ActualAssessment` will be attached to the context and automatic relationship fixup will popolate `TheEvent.ActualAssessment` **if**

- you don't disable change tracking
- the relationship is not many-to-many

As a side note: You can use `AsEnumerable()` instead of the first `ToList()` to avoid the unnecessary overhead of creating a list of anonymous objects.

**Edit**

For a many-to-many relationship or in case of disabled change tracking you must set the navigation property after the DB query is materialized, like so for example:

```
            .Select(evntInfo => {
                evntInfo.TheEvent.ActualAssessment = evntInfo.ActualAssessment;
                return new ExtendedEvent {
                    TheEvent = evntInfo.TheEvent,
                    SomeExtraData = evntInfo.SomeExtraData
                };
            })
```

Comment: And how would you deal with causing a many-to-many to be concretized with eager loading in a wrapper object?