# Why doesn't entity framework concretize my entity's one to many relationship?

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, entity

I am using a code-first approach with Entity Framework, and a repository pattern to get entities back from my database.  In my data model, each `OverallEvent` has many `EventInConcept` children.  I want my `GetEvents` method to return an `IList` of `OverallEvent`s, and I want the children of the aforementioned relationship to be concretized such that they can be accessed outside my `DbContext` (which `AssessmentSystemContext` is).  This is the code I currently have:

```
public IList<OverallEvent> GetEvents() {
    using (var context = new AssessmentSystemContext()) {
        return context.OverallEvents
            .Select(evnt => new {
                OverallEvent = evnt,
                // evnt.EventsInConcept is a public virtual ICollection<EventInConcept>
                ConcreteEventsInConcept = evnt.EventsInConcept
            })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(evntData => {
                evntData.OverallEvent.EventsInConcept = evntData.ConcreteEventsInConcept.ToList();
//              foreach (var eic in evntData.OverallEvent.EventsInConcept) {
//                  eic.Name = eic.Name;
//              }
                return evntData.OverallEvent;
            })
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

It gives me back a list of `OverallEvent` entities, which is fine, but the trouble is that if I try to access the child relationship `EventsInConcept`, I get an error.  For example:

```
EventRepository repoEvent = new EventRepository();
var gotEvents = repoEvent.GetEvents();
var firstEventInConcept = gotEvents[0].EventsInConcept.FirstOrDefault();
```

... gives me the error "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."

I understood from the answer to [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143268/how-to-include-complex-entity-fields-in-a-projected-entity-framework-object) that if I projected `EventsInConcept` into a wrapper object, then explicitly set it in a later `.Select` call (ie. `evntData.OverallEvent.EventsInConcept = evntData.ConcreteEventsInConcept.ToList();`), it would concretize this one:many relationship and I would be able to access `EventsInConcept` outside of the `DbContext`, but it isn't working here.  Note that if I uncomment the `foreach` loop, it starts working, so to get it to work I have to explicitly set a property on *every single entry* of `EventsInConcept`.  I don't really want to have to do this (I'm picking an arbitrary property, `.Name`, which feels wrong anyway).  Is there a better way?

Comment: Can't you just eager load your nested entities?

Comment: You mean using `.Include()`?  I can't do that because I'm actually doing something more complex than just a `.Select()` (I'm using a `.Skip()` and a `.Take()` as well, which means EF ignores `.Include()`s).  The example code is simplified and doesn't contain that bit.

Comment: Yes I meant `Include`. But why would EF ignore `Include`? `Include` just adds a `join` to the generated SQL so it returns more data, no matter what is the request complexity.

Comment: @ken2k See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13143504/178757).  `Include` is ignored in projections.  I don't know why Microsoft decided to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable lazy loading for this query. It is of no use in that situation and when you dispose the context after the entities have been retrieved:

```
public IList<OverallEvent> GetEvents() {
    using (var context = new AssessmentSystemContext()) {
        context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        return ...
    }
}
```

It might be possible that EF doesn't recognize that the collection has been loaded when you use a projection (instead of eager or explicit loading) and triggers lazy loading as soon as you access the collection.

Comment: But that's not a great solution, because it means that any other complex entities linked from `OverallEvent` will also be loaded even if I don't need to use them.

Comment: @Jez: Why? If you disable lazy loading only the related entities will be loaded you explicitly request for in your query and nothing more.

Comment: For some reason, this works!  Though I'd be interested as to why.  The SQL Server Profiler indicates that in both cases, the underlying SQL query is the same (it is OUTER JOINing the `EventInConcept` table), but with lazy loading disabled, it actually uses the data it gets back from the database to concretize the `EventsInConcept` collection.

Comment: @Jez: Yes, the query is the same. The difference is only that in case of enabled lazy loading EF will materialize dynamic proxies that try to load the collection again when you access it (probably because in case of a projection EF does not mark the collection as loaded since you set it manually in the second `Select`).